# How to upload file in Google drive through download link with Google drive Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Google drive API in my Asp.net MVC project and I want to get an idea about making a copy of file or Upload a file with Shared Link. So first understand the scenario.
A User generates a public download link of any file and provide it to my website. Any other user should be able to click on the download button. the specific shared file should be add into the user's drive. Not in (Share With Me) but in User's own Drive Storage.
If anyone have a idea to this so please let me know.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this but the best way would depend on what access you would have, as in I am assuming the application would be authenticated to upload the user's google drive. One way could be that using the google drive api you could download the file to a directory then perform an upload to the destination then delete the downloaded file. You can check out the documentation developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sir.